# Continuity and Uniqueness Explanation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I'm reviewing for an exam and I'm attempting to understand this problem (not homework):

Verify that both $y_1(t) = 1 − t$ and $y_2(t) = −t^2/4$ are solutions of the initial value
problem

$$y' = \frac{−t + \sqrt{t^2 + 4y}}{2} \;,\; y(2) = −1.$$

Where are these solutions valid?

(b) Explain why the existence of two solutions of the given problem does not contradict
the uniqueness

---

I'm trying to figure out why that is, but if someone could help paint a picture for me, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: where are the derivatives?

Comment: Of y1 and y2 you mean?  I just added a prime to the main expression, which was missing before.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: you already did the necessary corrections